# Extract part of string using REGEX

Tags: regex

I need to extract following from below string using REGEX, can anyone help

```
String = "[payment is made within [ 10  ] Business Days  of its due date.]"
```

Output:

```
[ 10  ] Business Days
```

Comment: You need to specify what exactly are you looking for. Is is a substring containing a number of "Business Days"? Is it the string containing 2 words after number 10 in square brackets? Spaces are important too. Will there always be a space between number and brackets? Add more details.

Comment: If you just want to find that substring with varying number of days, it would be `([ [0-9]+ ] Business Days)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
s/^\[payment is made within (\[ [0-9]* \]) Business Days.*$/\1 Business Days/
```

Comment: can you try here - https://regexr.com... im trying above regex and it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe `[0-9]+`? Also I don't use regexp much, but is `s/*/*/` a standard syntax or is it specific to `sed`?

Comment: It is working. I am using PCRE engine. Which one are you using?

Comment: Use this link https://regexr.com/40cfn. And then under tool, add following text- "\1 Business Days" without quotes. And use replace option.

Comment: @IcedLance It is specific to SED. But I feel it as good shorthand to write whenever somebody asks for regex.

Comment: @nitzien - how can we prefix this with the below line

Comment: payment is made within

Comment: as we have mentioned business day at the end in REGEX... can i prefix something at start also... in this case "payment is made within"

Comment: Can you please give me full text that you need as output?

Comment: Updated answer with what you needed